# Is it possible to read in specific bands from a multi-band raster with gdal or rasterio?

Tags: python, gdal, multi-band, rasterio

I wasn't able to find an answer to this after searching the help files and the forums.

I have a (virtual) raster with 60 bands, where each band represents a realization in time (think of frames of a video). I want to be able to load in cropped, specific band sets from this virtual raster without loading all of them--something like

```
myVRT = gdal.Open(vrtfile)
bands = myVRT.GetRasterBand([2,4,6,14,35])
cropped_bandstack = bands.ReadAsArray(
   xoff = xoffset,
   yoff = yoffset,
   xsize = xsz,
   ysize = ysz)
```

which would create an array with only bands 2,4,6,14, and 35.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this without loading each band separately and filling in a 3D matrix.

Another alternative that I also want to avoid is to re-create each of the individual cropped bands (which are also virtual), then create a new virtual raster stack using only the bands I want, and finally read it into an array.

I saw this was listed as a feature to add to rasterio but I couldn't find any evidence of it actually being added.

Edit: After receiving an answer, I think I should clarify that I'm asking if this can be performed in a single call, rather than implementing a loop to read each band individually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read specific bands in a single call using rasterio by passing a list/tuple of band numbers (Following the GDAL convention, bands are indexed from 1):

```
import rasterio
rasterio.__version__
'1.0a8'

dataset = rasterio.open('multiband.tif')

dataset.count
4

dataset.read((1,2)) #read 1st two bands into an array.

array([[[ 85,  98,  75, ...,  53,  55,  55],
        [ 84,  94,  76, ...,  54,  55,  54],
        [ 68,  60,  55, ...,  53,  54,  53],
        ...,
        [ 67,  67,  66, ...,  63,  63,  62],
        [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]],

       [[ 78,  88,  65, ...,  41,  43,  45],
        [ 77,  84,  66, ...,  42,  43,  44],
        [ 61,  51,  46, ...,  41,  42,  43],
        ...,
        [ 77,  77,  77, ...,  71,  70,  69],
        [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 207, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, ..., 191,   0, 135]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 4):

This appears to work with `rasterio`

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

vstack = '/path/to/virtual_stack.vrt'
bands = [2,4,6,14,35]

# define cropping window ((row_start, row_stop), (col_start, col_stop))
window = ((10, 50), (30, 40))

with rasterio.open(vstack) as src:
    # Create zero array (you may want to set dtype too)
    array = np.zeros((window[0][1] - window[0][0],
                      window[1][1] - window[1][0],
                      len(bands)))
    # Fill the array
    for i, band in enumerate(bands):
        array[:,:,i] = src.read(band, window=window)
```

Comment: Aye, and you can do the same loop with my original code. I guess I was asking whether it could be done in a single call, rather than reading each band one at a time. I suppose that any solution would be doing pretty much exactly what you've posted, so there wouldn't be a major speedup.

Comment: That's correct. I'm quite sure this can't be done without a loop or list comprehension, and if it could I doubt there would be any speedup.

Comment: Yes you can read multiple bands in a single call, i.e. `src.read(bandlist)`.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, that's very slick!!! `rasterio` never stops to impress me :)